# Flurry's not collecting any data from my iPhone-app

Tags: iphone, flurry

I want to use Flurry to collect some statistics, so I registered and created an app in Flurry. Then, I put the following code in my appDidFinishLaunching:

```
[FlurryAPI startSession:@"code here"];
```

Afterwards, I installed the app on my iPhone and ran it - but I don't see any data online. Am I missing something?

And is data also collected from the simulator?

Thanks a lot,

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you wait for the data to be processed before checking?  You may want to consider using Localytics (www.localytics.com) which is a real-time service so you can see the results of your tests immediately.

-- Henry

Comment: what's the average wait time?